# Groups not visible in powershell

Tags: 2010, powershell, groups

I made a few new Sharepoint groups in one of my test site collections. I can see them in the web interface, I can work with them, so everything seems to be fine.
But I cannot use these groups with powershell. This script:

```
$site = New-Object -Type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite -ArgumentList "https://mysite"
$groups = $site.RootWeb.Groups
foreach($i in $groups)
{
write-host $i.name
}
```

Returns all other groups, but not the new ones. The site was recently restored from a site collection backup and that looks like a break point. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `Groups` with `SiteGroups`.

Try using the below command:

```
$site = New-Object -Type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite -ArgumentList "https://mysite"
$groups = $site.RootWeb.SiteGroups 
foreach($i in $groups)
{
   write-host $i.name
}
```

It will list all the groups in the site collection

Reference - [SPWeb.SiteGroups property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.sitegroups.aspx)